# How to do sharding and replication of Orient DB database

Tags: spring-mvc, database-replication, sharding, orientdb, jdbctemplate

I am using spring MVC + orient db alongwith jdbcTemplate. I want to make my database as distributed with multi-master replication. Also I want to  do sharding of db. How can i achieve it. Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

OrientDB replication model is very simple.
You can start multiple instances just running ./dserver.sh instead of ./server.sh
By default they will join using multicast and data will be replicated across your nodes. If you want to do sharding, you have to define which data clusters are deployed on each node.

Here you can find all the practical info

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Architecture.html